Can SAP GUI scripts be executed from an ABAP program?
I created a SAP GUI script here and can play it back without any problems:

Is there a way to play it back from my own ABAP program?
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report z_monitor_gui_script
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
REPORT z_monitor_gui_script.
" execute C:\Users\test\SAP\sap-gui-scripts\Monitor.vbs ...

I tried to experiment with SM69 + and the SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE function call so far, but nothing has worked.
I don't really know what I'm doing though, so unsure if that's the right direction or not.

SM69 runs a command on the ABAP backend server only (often Linux/Unix). Where do you want to run your script? On the user's laptop? The script can run only on Windows or Java (SAP GUI for Windows/SAP GUI for Java). To run a file on the user's laptop, use cl_gui_frontend_services=>execute.

I want to run it just like the Record and Playback does it - I don't know what it actually does. Thanks for the hint - I will research this cl_gui... class

If the file is located on the user's laptop, the user may run the ABAP program below via SAP GUI for Windows, and it will run the script via his own application SAP GUI for Windows (for information, the VBS script may implement a logic to run on another SAP GUI session than the current one, where the ABAP program runs):
  REPORT z_demo.
  DATA(vbs_path) = `C:\Users\test\SAP\sap-gui-scripts\Monitor.vbs`.

  DATA(application) = `%windir%\syswow64\wscript`.
  DATA(parameter) = `"` && vbs_path && `"`.
  cl_gui_frontend_services=>execute(
      EXPORTING
        application = application
        parameter   = parameter
        synchronous = ' '
      EXCEPTIONS
        others      = 1 ).


it worked perfectly, thanks a lot!
